# AliExpress API "undefined index/trying to get property of non-object" - Displaying Products via blade with the laravel 5.4 framework

Tags: php, laravel, api, undefined

I am trying to display AliExpress products on my website through the use of it's API, using the laravel framework. I have researched throughly and haven't found a solution to the error/errors I am receiving.

Code: In my Controller (using the clchangnet repo to make the calls to the api).

```
 public function searchItems($search)
{
    $lppfields = [
        // 'categoryId' => '1501',
        'keywords' => $search,
    ];

    $products = $this->listPromotionProduct($lppfields);
   // dd($products);
    return view('product.product', compact('products'));
}
```

When I dd($products), it returns the products like so:

```
array:3 [▼
  "result" => array:2 [▼
    "totalResults" => 11680
    "products" => array:20 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "imageUrl" => "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1uUZ_JXXXXXXaXFXXq6xXFXXXo/1-Pair-Magnetic-Silicone-Toe-Ring-Diet-Slimming-Spa-Foot-Massager-Slim-Toe-Ring-Popular-Fitness.jpg"
        "productUrl" => "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Free-Shipping-Magnetic-Silicon-Double-Toe-Ring-Diet-Slimming-Spa-Massage-Ultra-Popular-Fitness-Slimming/1973015080.html"
        "productTitle" => "1 Pair Magnetic Silicone Toe Ring Diet Slimming Spa Foot Massager Slim Toe Ring Popular Fitness Slimming Weight Loss <font><b>Products</b></font>"
        "salePrice" => "US $0.83"
        "productId" => 1973015080
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "imageUrl" => "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1MalNRFXXXXaEapXXq6xXFXXXz/Hot-Temporary-tattoo-Gold-tattoo-Flash-Tattoos-Leaf-Tatoos-Metallic-Sex-font-b-Products-b-font.jpg"
        "productUrl" => "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Metalic-Leaf-Tatoos-Gold-Metallic-Temporary-Flash-Tattoos-Sex-Products-jewelry-etal-Bling-Henna-Tatouage/32409993510.html"
        "productTitle" => "Hot Temporary tattoo Gold tattoo Flash Tattoos Leaf Tatoos Metallic Sex <font><b>Products</b></font> jewelry Henna Tatouage Body art tatto stickers"
        "salePrice" => "US $0.54"
        "productId" => 32409993510
      ]
      2 => array:5 [▶]
      3 => array:5 [▶]
      4 => array:5 [▶]
      5 => array:5 [▶]
      6 => array:5 [▶]
      7 => array:5 [▶]
      8 => array:5 [▶]
      9 => array:5 [▶]
      10 => array:5 [▶]
      11 => array:5 [▶]
      12 => array:5 [▶]
      13 => array:5 [▶]
      14 => array:5 [▶]
      15 => array:5 [▶]
      16 => array:5 [▶]
      17 => array:5 [▶]
      18 => array:5 [▶]
      19 => array:5 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  "errorCode" => 20010000
  "keywords" => "product"
]
```

When trying to display the products (in this case the watches) in my view using blade template:

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
     <li>{{$product->imageUrl}}</li>
 @endforeach
```

I get the error:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web/autoimport/resources/views/product/product.blade.php)
```

I've also tried

```
<ul>
        @foreach($products as $product)
                <li>{{$product[0]->imageUrl}}</li>
        @endforeach

      <li>{{$products[0]->imageUrl}}</li>

      $foreach($products as $product)
        @foreach($product as $val)
            <li>{{$val->imageUrl}}</li>
        $endforeach
      @endforeach

      $foreach($products as $product => val)
            <li>{{$val->imageUrl}}</li>
      $endforeach

     @foreach($products as $product)
         <li>{{$product['productUrl']}}</li>
     @endforeach </ul>
```

And they either cause  a
"Undefined Index" or "Trying to get property of non-object" error

I'm most likely making a silly mistake, but I'm new to coding and have been working on this for the last 3 days. If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in the blade view file, This should work

```
@foreach($products['result']['products'] as $product)
            <li>{{$product['imageUrl']}}</li>
@endforeach
```

You are getting this error because you are trying to access the array as an object.

Seeing as you are using laravel you could try to create a new collection and use the magic get method to access the array as an object.

```
$productsCollection = collect($products);// or new Collection($products);

@foreach($products->result->products as $product)
            <li>{{$product->imageUrl}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you! The bottom one didn't work but your first suggestion worked perfectly! I appreciate your comments!

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because there is a syntax error in your blade file you are using $foreach instead of @foreach

```
    <ul>
    @foreach($products as $product)
            <li>{{$product[0]->imageUrl}}</li>
    @endforeach

  <li>{{$products[0]->imageUrl}}</li>
  //@foreach instead of $foreach
  $foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product as $val)
        <li>{{$val->imageUrl}}</li>
    $endforeach
  @endforeach

  $foreach($products as $product => val)
        <li>{{$val->imageUrl}}</li>
  $endforeach

 @foreach($products as $product)
     <li>{{$product['productUrl']}}</li>
 @endforeach </ul>
```